# ASP.Net Form submit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a search form that is fired from my grid view select button. It works fine when it loads as in the fields fill up with the selected row details as expected but when I change any field and click on update record it does not take the updated values that I just typed into the text box but seems to resave the original values . Please help

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class Search_Reporters : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Ingest;Integrated Security=True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //txt_rname.Enabled = false;
       // txt_rmobile.Enabled = false;
       // txt_remail.Enabled = false;

        con.Open();
       // string qry = "select * from Reporter where Reporter_ID=  " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "";
        lbl_1.Text = Session["id"].ToString();
        string qry = "select * from Reporter where Reporter_ID= " + Session["id"] + " ";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt); // table data-> data table
        con.Close();
        txt_rname.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
        txt_remail.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
        txt_rmobile.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();




    }

    protected void btn_edit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txt_rname.Enabled = true;
        txt_rmobile.Enabled = true;
        txt_remail.Enabled = true;
        lbl_remark.Text = "";
    }
    protected void btn_Save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        con.Open();
        string qry = "update Reporter  set Reporter_Name ='" + txt_rname.Text + "',Reporter_Email='" + txt_remail.Text + "',Reporter_Mobile = '" + txt_rmobile.Text + "' where Reporter_ID = " +lbl_1.Text+  "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        int x = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (x == 1)
        {
            //lbl_remark.Text = "Updated Successfully";
            Response.Redirect("Reporters_remarks.aspx");
        }
        else
        {
            lbl_remark.Text = "error";
        }
        con.Close();


    }
    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        lbl_remark.Text = "";
        txt_rname.Text = "";
        txt_remail.Text = "";
        txt_rmobile.Text = "";

        con.Open();
        string qry = "select * from Reporter where Reporter_ID=  " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "";
        //string qry = "select * from Reporter where Reporter_ID= "+Session["id"]+" ";
         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
         SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt); // table data-> data table
        con.Close();
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
        lbl_remark.Text = "User Not Found";

        }
         else
         {
         txt_rname.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
          txt_remail.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
          txt_rmobile.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();

        }


    }


}
```

HTML Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Reporters_Search.aspx.cs" Inherits="Search_Reporters" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .style1
        {
            width: 100%;
        }
        .style2
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
        .style3
        {
            text-align: right;
            width: 648px;
        }
        .style4
        {
            text-align: center;
            width: 648px;
        }
        .style5
        {
            text-decoration: underline;
            font-size: larger;
        }
        .style6
        {
            text-align: center;
            height: 17px;
        }
        .style7
        {
            height: 17px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

        <table class="style1">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2" style="text-align: center" class="style5">
                    <strong>Reporter Search</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style4" style="text-align: right">
                    Reporter ID:</td>
                <td>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Reporter_ID" 
                        DataValueField="Reporter_ID" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
                        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IngestConnectionString %>" 
                        SelectCommand="SELECT [Reporter_ID] FROM [Reporter] ORDER BY [Reporter_ID]">
                    </asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_edit" runat="server" Text="Edit" Width="60px" 
                        onclick="btn_edit_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    Reporter Name :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_rname" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    Reporter Email :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_remail" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style3">
                    Reporter Mobile :</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txt_rmobile" runat="server" Width="200px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style6">
                    </td>
                <td class="style7">
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style6" colspan="2">
                    <asp:Label ID="lbl_remark" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style6">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td class="style7">
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_Save" runat="server" style="text-align: center" Text="Update Record" 
                        Width="120px" onclick="btn_Save_Click" />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="style4">
                    &nbsp;</td>
                <td>
                    &nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IsPostBack() is missed in your page load. Put your code in the block if(!IsPostBack() ){ // put code which you want to run on page load not on the page post back}.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your quick response . I am new to .net so please excuse my stupid questions. when I put my page load code as you said I get the following erroe The name 'IsPostBack' does not exist in the current context

Comment: What have you change please show your code.  Please refer this http://net-informations.com/faq/asp/ispostback.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Pradeep. The following code fixed my problem

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack )    
        {


            txt_rname.Enabled = false;
            txt_rmobile.Enabled = false;
            txt_remail.Enabled = false;

            con.Open();
            // string qry = "select * from Reporter where Reporter_ID=  " + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "";
            lbl_1.Text = Session["id"].ToString();
            string qry = "select * from Reporter where Reporter_ID= " + Session["id"] + " ";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt); // table data-> data table
            con.Close();
            txt_rname.Text = dt.Rows[0][1].ToString();
            txt_remail.Text = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            txt_rmobile.Text = dt.Rows[0][3].ToString();

        }
        else
        {
        }


    }
```